# Converting from XMLSchema datatype to Java int

Tags: java, sparql, jena, dbpedia

I am working on a project that involves fetching data from Dbpedia and I was wondering whether there is anyway to convert the the object returned from a dbpedia query i.e a XMLSchema#double into a java int so that I can perform operations on it and modify the data for my use. I am using jena to fetch the data from the sparql endpoints jena provide. I tried using the toString method to change the RDFnode into a string and than converting into an int/double, but that doesnt seem to work and gives me the exception that is listed below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "147181000000^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
```

Does anyone here have a work around this problem??

Comment: Also asked and answered on jena-users mailing list - http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-jena-users/201204.mbox/%3c61D2E544-F3DA-4649-BBF4-B242CBA5952D@cray.com%3e

Comment: yep i asked them there too, nd got the answer

Comment: only just now saw that you *did* get an answer there, so have deleted my alternative answer as unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

After Converting to String it look like:
"147181000000^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double"

And you want to convert into int/double for that you have to separate only first number from this string
Number= 147181000000 . 
You can use indexOf or split method to get Number from the String.

Sample Code:

```
 String number = "147181000000^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#double";
    number = number.subString(0,nuber.indexOf(^));
    int num = Integer.ParseInt(number);
```